# How to space columns in HighCharts

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have a parent container with fixed width and height. The graph that is rendered using highcharts gets contained inside the parent container. Can someone tell me what should be done to make the chart container scrollable and space the labels and bars properly so that all the labels are clearly visible and bars are spaced well. Please find the jsfiddle for better understanding https://jsfiddle.net/z5wqgkm9/

Have tried enabling scroll using

```
 scrollbar: {
             enabled: true
            }
```

But this is not of much help

Comment: How about using overflow: scroll on the parent div? https://jsfiddle.net/z5wqgkm9/2/

Comment: @morganfree, you are awesome :) thanks that helps it. If you place this as an answer i can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I placed my solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `overflow: scroll` on the parent div should do the work.

```
<div style="width:500px;height:600px; overflow: scroll;">
    <div id="recoranks" style="width: 400%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>
```

example: jsfiddle.net/z5wqgkm9/2

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that highcharts uses the container width to render the chart. So no matter what you set it will conform to the parent container width and height.

To be able to render the chart bigger width-wise or height-wise or both and keeping it within a contained box with scrolls, you can take advantage of the float property which renders the position of the element to not conform to the parent.

Here is what you have to do.

First. Add another div container on top of the main div `<div style="width:500px;height:600px">`

Second. give the top container a css class of say `.main-container` and give the inner div a css class of say `.inner-container`.

So your html will look something like the following

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div id="recoranks" style="min-width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto">  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now. Add the following css classes:

```
.main-container {
  width:500px;
  height:600px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.inner-container {
  width:700px;
  height:580px;
  float:left
}
```

And your all set.

Little detail on what we did. We covered the chart div with another div. This top div will be the width and height limited container having the scrolls. We gave it the width and height that we want the chart container to have. Also we asked it to hide the overflow on the y axis and make the overflow scrollable to the x axis as your scenario only wants to scroll horizontally based on increased width to clearly add spacing in the chart bars. You can change these overflow settings to your needs.

What we did to the inner chart div container is make it float so that it does not conform to the parent's width as the parent thinks that it does not have any block element to add space in it. Now the width and height we set to this float container will help control the actual chart width and height that it will render to.

Sample with above solution using your code: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/QGbxRw

Comment: can the size of chart be increased dynamically? i mean the width of the columns and spacing between labels ?

Comment: You can use view port measuring unit on the width of the .inner-container class e.g. width:100vw; This will make the width of the chart dynamic and responsive.

Comment: thanks nasir, but morganfree's solution is more elegant and simple

Comment: No problem. My answer may help someone with a specific need for it. So no worries. Glad it worked out for you.